# Undo button for drawing app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, undo

I made an iPad drawing app and I want it to have an "Undo" button that will remove the last object drawn on the screen.

How can do that? I already have the button connected to its outlet and action.

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSUndoManager`. Build a system that uses it. Let us know how that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you will need to keep a version of the the image before the new object is drawn on it, and if the user decides to abandon the drawing, revert back to the previous image.

If you want more then one level of undo it may be easier to keep a description of all of the actions performed by the user and repeat them up to the last undo.

Comment: or, for each action, keep an undo action (and a redo action).